# How can I store a dynamic menu of dependent items efficiently?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a user-controlled menu of dependent drop downs (5 total) that is used to narrow down the specific root cause of a problem. The information is easily stored in a database (below), but I am having problems coming up with a way to efficiently store this in memory so that I can create a set of 5 combo boxes with each subsequent box populated when the parent changes. I don't want to query the table after each drop down change because it introduces a noticeable delay.

My table looks like this:

```
RootItem1   SubItem1    SubItemA    SubItemB    SubItemC
RootItem1   SubItem1    SubItemA    SubItemB    SubItemD
RootItem1   SubItem1    SubItemA    SubItemB    SubItemE
RootItem1   SubItem1    SubItemA    SubItemF    
RootItem1   SubItem1    SubItemA    SubItemF    SubItemG
RootItem1   SubItem1    SubItemA    SubItemF    SubItemH
RootItem1   SubItem1    SubItemI    SubItemJ    SubItemK
RootItem1   SubItem1    SubItemI    SubItemJ    SubItemL
RootItem1   SubItem2
RootItem1   SubItem2    SubItemM
RootItem1   SubItem2    SubItemM    SubItemN
RootItem2   SubItem3    SubItemO    SubItemP
RootItem2   SubItem3    SubItemQ    SubItemR
RootItem3   SubItem4    SubItemS    SubItemT
RootItem3   SubItem4    SubItemU
RootItem3   SubItem4    SubItemV    SubItemW    SubItemX
RootItem3   SubItem5    SubItemY
RootItem3   SubItem5    SubItemY    SubItemZ
```

It's important to notice that not all items use all 5 sub-groups.

My initial thought was to create a 5D dictionary to store this, then match the child combo boxes to populate that box. The first part of the dictionary would look like this:

```
d = {
    'RootItem1': {
        'SubItem1': {
            'SubItemA': {
                'SubItemB': ['SubItemC', 'SubItemD', 'SubItemE'],
                'SubItemF': ['', 'SubItemG', 'SubItemH'],
            }
            'SubItemI': {
                'SubItemJ': ['SubItemK', 'SubItemL']
            }
        },
        'SubItem2': {
            '': {},
            'SubItemM': {
                '': [],
                'SubItemN': ['']
            },
            'SubItemO': {
                'SubItemP': ['']
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

My issue with this, is that it gets very hard to understand when upper levels have no child elements. There are a lot of `''` keys.

How can I efficiently generate a way to store the table from above into a datastructure I can use to quickly populate 5 drop down boxes with each lower box getting it's values from the previous one?

Comment: My first thought is to just store the whole table in memory. How big is it? For just text like that you could store a few thousand rows in a few MBs of RAM.

Comment: Also, does a subitem always lead to the same subitems? From your table example I don't think they do, but if they do then you could use a graph. For example does SubItemA always lead to SubItemB and SubItemF, or can it change?

Comment: It's very surprising that reading from a database produces a delay, given that the relevant table is so small. It strongly suggests that there is some inefficiency in how you are populating the combo-boxes from the database.

Comment: @CornSmith, The items can change.

Comment: @NewGuy, I thought so, in that case there's no getting around building some kind of nested structure like you have with your nest `dict`s. If I was building this I'd probably use nested `dict`s too. I think the way you're doing it is good, and accounting for those empty `['']` parts won't be that annoying. However if you end up wanting to store more than text then you could make nested objects instead.